# Is it possible to parent theme without affecting child theme?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I would like to use the current code of my website which I have customized as the child theme and switch to that so that I can update parent theme(hepta) with updates from the Theme Builder.

Is it at all possible? Can you let me know the best way forward?

Comment: Yes it won't affect if you did all your code in child theme only.

Comment: What is the best way forward?

Comment: of-course you need to take backup and update the theme

Answer (score 0):

Yes Its a wordpress recommended way that you have do all your customizations in child theme and when there is any theme update the update will not effect your customizations.
This is the best way to update parent theme.

Comment: Can I change the parent theme into a child theme?

Comment: Yes you can change the parent theme function into your child theme.
But first make sure that the parent theme have functions with statement link if(!function_exists('any_function'))